# Why the % wildcard is not working in SQL Server as contents of a variable?

Tags: sql-server, wildcard

I am puzzled with the use of `%` wildcard in variables.

For instances this will work:

```
SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE column LIKE 'blah%'
```

But this will not:

```
DECLARE @myvar AS varchar = 'blah%'

SELECT * 
FROM TABLE 
WHERE column LIKE @myvar
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks!

Comment: This [does work](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=bdb94519ad2b6a7049276ff5ccdf089e) -- as long as you don't make the mistake of [declaring `VARCHAR` without a length](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/09/bad-habits-to-kick-declaring-varchar-without-length).

Comment: `DECLARE @myvar AS varchar = 'blah%'` = `DECLARE @myvar AS varchar(1) = 'blah%'` = `DECLARE @myvar AS varchar(1) = 'b'`, which contains no wild card characters.

Comment: This works, but declare `@myvar` as `vachar(20)`, not as `varchar`. (which is equivalent of `varchar(1)`)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

By declaring as a variable the wildcard becomes just another literal.  Also, a length should be assigned to the VARCHAR.  Then this works

```
DECLARE @myvar varchar(10) = 'blah'
SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE column like @myvar+'%'
```

Please see this WORKING example

```
drop table if exists #Stock;
go
create table #Stock(
  some_col      varchar(10) not null);

insert #Stock(some_col) values ('Stock abc'),('Stock abc'),('Stock abc');

DECLARE @myvar varchar = 'Stock%';
SELECT * FROM #Stock WHERE some_col like @myvar;

DECLARE @myvar2 varchar = 'Stock';
SELECT * FROM #Stock WHERE some_col like @myvar2+'%';
```